# Is there an 'undo send" feature in Outlook WebApp 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, outlook-web-access

I'm new to Outlook. I have been using Gmail for a long time and my company switched to Outlook. Gmail has an "undo send" feature. I wanted to know if Outlook Web App 2010 has a similar feature. I'm not looking for the recall option.

Comment: I’m pretty sure Google can’t do magic, so this probably only works when sending from GMail to GMail. Are you talking about mails that are delivered without leaving your company’s Exchange server?

Comment: I'm talking about a feature that delays an email for like 5 to 10 seconds before leaving my mailbox. Gmail has this feature and I have been using this for the past 3-4 years.

Comment: Ah, that is not what you asked!!

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to delay the sending of your emails. This can be easily achieved in a desktop version of Outlook by using outgoing rules (**defer delivery by a number of minutes** action). But unfortunately you can't do it in OWA because there are no outgoing rules there.